# Custom folder for dependency JAR in Jetty

Tags: jar, jetty, classloader

I am using Jetty 9.2. I have a dependency JAR which I am currently placing in "lib/ext/" folder thus it loads automatically.  I have also tried using "--lib=%EXT_JAR PATH%" in "start.bat" of Jetty. This loads the JAR on startup. Is it possible to keep the JAR in a custom folder and make it to load automatically on start classloader without specifying in "start.bat" file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `ext` module to your `${jetty.base}` configuration and then place the jars in `${jetty.base}/lib/ext`.  (Note: these jars are only available to the server classloader, not the webapps)

Command line example:

```sh
# Do all of the commands from your jetty-base
$ cd /path/to/mybase

# Add 'ext' module (to either start.ini or start.d/ext.ini)
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=ext

# Copy jars into place
$ cp /home/malini/code/project/target/special.jar /path/to/mybase/lib/ext/

# Verify that lib is present in server classpath/classloader
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config

# Run jetty
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

Comment: Many thanks.My question was to have custom folder. I should have included exact scenario. I hv 'Sample.jar' in folder "myJAR" located in "/to/mybase".Is it possible to load 'Sample.JAR' on startup.I have tried by including "--lib=mybase/myJAR/Sample.jar".This loads 'Sample.jar' on startup. But this method requires specifying the JAR name in "start.bat".If I add a new JAR, it requires to specify the new JAR name in "start.bat".Is it possible to load all JAR in "/to/mybase/myJAR" to load on startup.Yes, ext folder solves this purpose,I would like to pack all my JARs together in a custom folder.